# Training on a single class car but predicting some other class

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Deformable fpn to train on a single class for e.g car and i want to predict car in my testing script, but its predicting for e.g airplane. What should i do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question falls way below the standard for a good question on this site.  Review the [guide to asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make sure to post clear, specific questions typically with sample minimal and reproducable code.